# Scala Slick filter two conditions - error session is not applicable

Tags: postgresql, scala, slick

I am using Scala and Slick and I am trying to execute simple query with two conditions

```
import JiraData._
import org.scala_tools.time.Imports._

import scala.slick.driver.PostgresDriver.simple._

val today = new DateTime()
val yesterday = today.plusDays(-1)

implicit val session = Database.forURL("jdbc:postgresql://localhost/jira-performance-manager",
    driver = "org.postgresql.Driver",
    user = "jira-performance-manager",
    password = "jira-performance-manager").withSession {
    implicit session =>
        val activeUsers = users.filter(_.active === true)
        for (activeUser <- activeUsers) {
            val activeUserWorkogs = worklogs.filter(x => x.username === activeUser.name && x.workDate === yesterday)
        }
}
```

But I receive error:

```
Error:(20, 95) value === is not a member of scala.slick.lifted.Column[org.scala_tools.time.Imports.DateTime]
 Note: implicit value session is not applicable here because it comes after the application point and it lacks an explicit result type
            val activeUserWorkogs = worklogs.filter(x => x.username === activeUser.name && x.workDate === yesterday)
                                                                                                      ^
```

What's wrong here? How can I get list of results filtered by two conditions?

Answer (score 0):

scala-tools.time uses JodaDateTime. See https://github.com/jorgeortiz85/scala-time/blob/master/src/main/scala/org/scala_tools/time/Imports.scala . Slick does not have built-in support for Joda. There is Slick Joda mapper: https://github.com/tototoshi/slick-joda-mapper . Or it is easy to add yourself: http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/2.1.0/userdefined.html#using-custom-scalar-types-in-queries

As a side-note: Something like

```
for (activeUser <- activeUsers) {
    val activeUserWorkogs = worklogs.filter(...)
```

looks like going into the wrong direction. It will run another query for each active user. Better is to use a join or run a single accumulated query for the work logs of all active users.

Comment: I understand your point - thanks for this. But for now I need to solve the problem first and work on optimization only later if it will be needed.  Btw, I resolved this issue by using single filter and then using IF to check second condition. This code is bad but it works. I don't understand why two filters don't work.